# Strings subtle differences In Java

Tags: java

```
public class StringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "java";
        String s2 = "ja" + "va";

        String s3 = "ja";
        String s4 = s3 + "va";

        System.out.println(s1 == s2);
        System.out.println(s1 == s4);
    }
}
```

First ***System.out.println(...);*** statement as expected outputs true, but why is second statement showing false as output?

I want to know which string is created in pool area and which in non-pool area of pool.

Comment: Was true before OP clarified

Comment: OP didn't clarify, @Kvass. The comment on an answer doesn't count. Feel like doing it for him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.equals()` to compare `String` objects.

```
{
    System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
    System.out.println(s1.equals(s4));
}
```

This is because the `==` operator on `Object` (here `String`) checks for same object **references**, for `String` equality you must use `.equals()`.

The `+` concatenation operator is effectively compiled down from:

```
a + b (a, b type String)
```

to:

```
new StringBuffer(a).append(b) (loading String in the common pool)
```

On the other hand, in the following code:

```
String s1 = "java";
String s2 = "ja" + "va";
// "ja" appends to "va". As the compiler optimization pass realizes
// that "ja" + "va" is literal "java", it burns down the two strings into
// the same literal as s1.

String s3 = "ja";
String s4 = s3 + "va";
// s3 appends to "va". As the compiler cannot effectively study the literal,
// It is allowed to be concatenated at run-time. This allows "java" to be
// created from the heap, instead of from the common pool.
```

Comment: but .equals() only compares contents not references.I wanna know which string is created in pool area and which in non-pool area of pool.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Xabster Unfortunately, I cannot delete an accepted answer, less to I would plagiarize your answer. My post was written before OP clarified with comments.

Comment: @Aamir if the answer is incorrect / to what isn't your question, why have you accepted it?

Comment: @Xabster how come it doesn't? The question is, "why doesn't s1==s4".

Answer (score 1):

String literals in Java are interned (put into a cached string pool). Literals is when they're written purely in the code with " " around them.

When an entire expression of string literals (in your case concatenations) can be evaluated at compile time, such strings are also interned.

You intern `"java"` and `"ja"`. The compiler could have been smart enough to see that s3 does not change between declaration+initialization but it does not, because it's not final.

Declaring `s3` to be `final` will yield true for 2nd SOP. So will adding `s4 = s4.intern();` before printing.

Edit: you asked "What exactly is s4 = s4.intern()":

s4.intern() will look through the pool of cached strings and return the cached string that is `equal` to s4 from the pool. Then it is assigned to s4 again. So: it replaces the s4 reference with the cached version if it exists. [Sideeffect: if it wasn't in the pool, it will be added and the reference is unchanged].

Answer (score 0):

`==` tests for reference equality, while `.equals()` tests for value equality.

Only use `==` when you have a guarantee that the same object will be used for both.

For more information: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
It also links to an article about string interning which is a mechanism of storing only one copy of each distinct string.

Comment: is it correct to say that String concatenation occurs at compile-time, but when references are involved like in my second SOP, then its a runtime situation and that is why false is the output.

Comment: I cannot comment with enough accuracy, however you may have a point. The compiler may be optimizing string concatenations, such that in your first case, it will be the same object, while in your second case, it won't